# In google-form script, unable to send spreadSheet as attached document of a mail

Tags: spreadsheet, google-forms

After filling a Google Form, I convert Questions/Responses in a SpreadSheet in order to send it to somebody.
- If I do NO conversion, the spreadSheet is received in my mailbox as a PDF file. Its OK.
- If I do some conversion (in the following code : .getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS), an exception occurs.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
...
var tempSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create( "reponses_candidat_" + candidat + "-" + dt + ".xlsx");

for (i in itemResponse) {

    var title = itemResponse[i].getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse[i].getResponse().toString();

    tempSheet.appendRow( [ title, answer] )  ;
}

  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail(mail,
            "Answer for 'FormulaireDeTest1' for " + candidat + ", filled at " + dt,
            "results are in attached file.\n\n",
            {name:"De la part du google-form", attachments: [tempSheet.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)]});
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("unable to send mail. err > " + err);
  }
```

And exception is :
Exception: Conversion of format application/pdf to format application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet is not available.

The original document is a spreadSheet, and the MailApp do as it was a PDF.

Some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve the problem. This send the link on the Drive file:

```
  var xFile;

    // ajouter "oauthScopes": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
  try {
    xFile = DriveApp.getFileById(tempSheet.getId());
    console.log("DriveApp.getFileById ok");
  } catch(err) {
     console.log("Drive.Files.get > err > " + err);
  }

  try {
    xFile.setSharing( DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    console.log("setSharing ok");
  } catch(err) {
     console.log("xFile.setSharing > err > " + err);
  }

  console.log( "owner.mail=" + tempSheet.getOwner().getEmail());

  var sInfos = "";
  try {    
    sInfos = "file_name: " + tempSheet.getName() + "\n" + "url:" + "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + tempSheet.getId();

    MailApp.sendEmail(mail,
                    "Test du questionnaire 'FormulaireDeTest1' pour " + candidat + ", remplit a " + dt,
                    "Les resultats sont en pièce jointe.\n\n" +
                    sInfos,
                    {name:"De la part du google-form"} );
  }catch(err) {
    console.log("impossible d'emettre un mail > err > " + err);
  }
```

Best regards.